# Is there a clean way of conditionally increasing or decreasing a value?

Tags: javascript

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var direction = (getState() < state) ? -1 : +1;         //check direction
var state = state + direction
```

But I don't like this solution at all. Would like something like:

```
var state = (getState() < state) ? state++ : state--;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var state = state + direction
> ```

This is either a redeclaration or something that doesn’t work, so

```
state += direction;
```

which I guess you can fold into one line if you were satisfied with the post(in|de)crement.

```
state += getState() < state ? -1 : +1;
```

and I think that’s as readable as that operation gets.

If you were doing something only *slightly* different (that involved not changing `state` when `getState() === state`), you could use `Math.sign`!

```
state += Math.sign(getState() - state);
```

This is a nice and clean solution, so maybe you can change the problem to suit it. =)

Comment: actually the last one works for me, this code only runs when state != getState()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary without assignment.

```
getState() < state ? state++ : state--;
```

or

```
state += getState() < state || -1;
```

Comment: He said "clean". **;-)**

Comment: Oh man, the edit with the second option's even worse. Don't, please just....don't. :-)

Comment: I like the first one. Why not?

Comment: @Himmators: Abuse of conditional operator to not produce a value. You can use it anyway.

Comment: @Ryan thanks, I got that, but the first one, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Himmators: That *is* the first one. `?:` is the conditional operator.

Comment: aha, I thought it was the &&